# Is the binding in Excel application persisted after closing the file and opening again

Tags: office-js

I am developing an Excel application add-in using office.js. Can someone tell me is a binding that is created in an Excel application persisted? If I close the file and open it again, will I still have the binding in the Excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the binding is persisted in the document and can be accessed across different sessions, users, platforms, and machines. However, it can only be referenced by the add-in that created it (eg. the Uber add-in cannot retrieve the bindings set by the PayPal add-in).

Often developers design their add-ins so that when the page loads, the add-in checks for the list of bindings that already exist, using [Bindings.getAllAsync](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.getallasync) and then iterating through the array. Another common pattern is to store information about bindings in the Settings object.

Note that if you want to continue getting binding-related API events in subsequent sessions, you need to call [Binding.addHandlerAsync()](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.addhandlerasync) for *every session* that you want to get the events for.

Comment: hi, i could get the binding but i noticed binding events are not getting called, after i opened the file again, i did call addHandlerAsync again, also i tried removing the event and adding it again, that did not worked.

Comment: I have observed that bindings are related to add-ins as well. Not sure as I have not investigated further but I have seen changing the ClientId of the add-in and the bindings were not visible anymore. They were in the XML/ZIP file though.